# While Installing firessh I get the following ERROR

Tags: git, github, terminal, installation

I am trying to install all these 3 things to make it actually work:

- https://github.com/MrAlex94/Waterfox (I have installed this but I cant add the firessh as a plugin)
- https://github.com/mimecuvalo/firessh (after executing in terminal)

```
git clone git://github.com/mimecuvalo/firessh.git
git submodule init
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

- https://github.com/mimecuvalo/paramikojs (0 description how to use it)

Comment: Shouldn't you start with `git init` or `git clone`?

Comment: I did I just have posted this part of the code because this is where I have gotten the error message the other is in the git description. But I will edit it there. No worries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `git clone` you need to enter the cloned repository:

```
cd firessh
```

Then run other `git` commands.

You could've cloned with submodules:

```
git clone --recursive git://github.com/mimecuvalo/firessh.git
```

Comment: ```cd firessh``` solved the error, While I was in firessh I have done this ```USERNAME$ git clone https://github.com/mimecuvalo/paramikojs```

Comment: it have downloaded it but I don't know where to put ```paramikojs ``` and how to staff the whole thing in to waterfox browser (that is running like a normal browser)

Comment: I have executed this as well  before posting the stack overflow question ```git clone --recursive git://github.com/mimecuvalo/firessh.git ```

Comment: Either `git clone --recursive git://github.com/mimecuvalo/firessh.git && cd firessh` or `git clone git://github.com/mimecuvalo/firessh.git && cd firessh && git submodule init && git submodule update`